# What is the correct order of the commands to replace my current kernel?

Tags: apt, software-installation, kernel

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Server (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)

I have three kernels installed:

```
4.15.0.39-generic
4.15.0.44-generic
4.15.0.45-generic
```

Please advise the correct order of the following commands:

```
sudo apt install linux-{image,headers,modules,modules-extra}-4.15.0-43-generic
sudo apt-mark hold linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic
sudo apt remove linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic
```

---

Previous advice from [the `ubuntu-server` mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server/2019-February/007813.html):

> Hi, the kernel with this fix for Bionic is present in the -proposed
>   repository, the version is 4.15.0-46-generic. To enable proposed
>   packages, you can check [0].
>
> Alternatively, you can install version 4.15.0-43-generic, which does
>   not have the offending patches that caused the tty issue.
>
> Cheers, Guilherme

Comment: That looks like a Mailing-List query?  If so why is it posted here?  If you've asked on the mailing list? why double-post here as well (it's not nice receiving the same request from multiple places from the same person, especially after you've just answered it elsewhere! [*not me in this case!*]).

Comment: @guiverc The advice I have received is excellent but I do not know how to carry it out. I have searched google and found the above commands but I am uncertain of the best order to action them.

Answer (score 0):

I actioned the commands in this order:

```
sudo apt install linux-{image,headers,modules,modules-extra}-4.15.0-43-generic    
sudo apt-mark hold linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic    
sudo apt remove linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic
```

I them reboot and uname -a confirmed the default kernel as: linux-4.15.0-43-generic

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.15.0.39 linux-headers-4.15.0.39-generic linux-image-4.15.0.39-generic linux-modules-4.15.0.39-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-39-generic
```

sudo reboot

Please copy/paste the result:

```
 dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Do you have problems with 45? keeping 2 is a better alternative. 46 is not shown here in Synaptic.

If so, remove 45 instead. There was a security update today, you should check for updates before.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.15.0.45 linux-headers-4.15.0.45-generic linux-image-4.15.0.45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0.45-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0.45-generic
```